# Confused in Android Button programing

Tags: android

i have some ImageButton when i pressed the button one by one letter have to show in my EditText.
And if it don't match to my given letter then my Image will vibrate.
Please help me i am new in android.
 here is my code
package com.example.image;

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     final ImageButton button1;
    final ImageButton button2;
    final ImageButton button3;
    final EditText input;
    Button chk;

     chk =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button1 =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    button2 =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    button3 =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    input =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             input.setText("a");
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             input.setText("B");
         }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ;
            input.setText("C");

        }
     });



    chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String check = input.getText().toString();

             if(check.contentEquals("ABC")){
                Vibrator vib =   (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

                // Vibrate for 100ms
                 vib.vibrate(300);
                 }
             else{
                input.setText("");
                Vibrator vib =  (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

                // Vibrate for 100ms
                vib.vibrate(300);
             }
        }


        });
       }
}
```

Comment: Post a question,at least...

Comment: Have you tried something? Any Attempt?

Comment: any one can help you only when you explain your problem properly. Post your code here.

Comment: this is my code.... -yuva

Comment: yes i am trying this code-  vjdhama

Comment: why you have written vibrate code in both condition ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the answer:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         input.setText(input.getText() + "A");
    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         input.setText(input.getText() + "B");
     }
});
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ;
        input.setText(input.getText() + "C");

    }
 });
```

Comment: again it make a problem when i pressed check button my apps force to stop i do't konow why?

Answer (score 0):

create a method like below

```
private void updateText(String char){
     String inputText = input.getText().toString() + char;
 input.setText(inputText);
 }
```

and then call this method from all your buttons (button1,button2,button3) clickListener like

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         updateText("A");
    }
});
```

Comment: this is not a problem.Problem is when i press a button it show a letter and then when i pressed a another button previous button removed and new button show. i want to show button contaniouly.
Suppose when i pressed a button editText show "a" and then i press the c Button editText will show "ac"

Comment: then what is the problem.

Comment: i want to show letter contaniously then i will press a chek button

Comment: do you want like when you press button1,EditText show "A",after that if you press button2, editText show "AB" and so on .correct me if I am wrong.